# Stop android adb ping programmatically and print statistics

Tags: android, shell, adb, ping

I am trying to send a ping for x amount of seconds instead of a certain amount of pings and gather the results. I notice that if I shell in and run "ping www.google.com" and stop it with CTRL + C it does not print the statistics, but if I run "ping -c5 www.google.com" the statistics will print. Is there a way to send the ping command, have it time out after a specified time, and then print the ping statistics?

Note: I am sending this programmatically with Java.

```
C:\Users\Field_Test>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ ping www.google.com
ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.46.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time
=55.7 ms
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time
=70.9 ms
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time
=60.8 ms
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time
=71.1 ms
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time
=69.8 ms
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f20.1e100.net (173.194.46.116): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time
=72.0 ms
^C
```

Comment: just for future reference for anyone else.... just shell in and type "ping" and you will see all of the values you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nm, found it. "-w#" will run for a specified time and print the statistics.

Comment: Accept your answer if you found it

Comment: I need to wait 2 days, then I can.